# Django and Javascript: Rendering HTML Form Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I'm running into an inconsistency issue when trying to render a form with select fields that are dependent on each other.  For this example, I have the objects 'League', 'Team', and 'Event'.  Teams are members of a League, and an Event is described as a matchup between two teams.

I have written javascript to handle the user's selection of league and team items, but it is behaving inconsistently.  For example, my django code yields this HTML output for leagues:

```
<p><label for="challengeLeague">League:</label> <select id="challengeLeague"               name="challengeLeague" onChange="getTeam()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">NBA</option>
    <option value="2">NFL</option>
    ...
</select></p>
```

and this for teams:

```
<p><label for="challengeTeam">Team:</label> <select id="challengeTeam" name="challengeTeam" onChange="getEvent()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1436">Arizona Cardinals</option>
    <option value="123">Atlanta Hawks</option>
    <option value="1810">Atlanta Falcons</option>
    ...
    </select></p>
```

However, when I try to access these value fields in Javascript to request more information from the server, I am having success with leagues and not teams.  For example:

```
document.getElementById("challengeLeague").value;
```

returns "1" for NBA as expected, but

```
document.getElementById("challengeTeam").value;
```

does not return a numerical value, but rather "Arizona Cardinals" instead of 1436.

Additionally, when I enter the getElementbyID function for teams into the javascript console it returns a list like:

```
<select id="challengeTeam" name="challengeTeam" onChange="getEvent()">
    <option value="Arizona Cardinals">Arizona Cardinals</option>
```

replacing the value integer with the name string.  I'm fairly experienced with Python, learning django, and a javascript newbie.  So I tend to debug in that reverse order, so far unsuccessfully.

Know what could be wrong?

EDIT:

For more information, both the League and Team form fields are generated in python as so:

```
self.fields['challengeLeague'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=League.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'getTeam()'}))
```

where getTeam and getEvent are javascript functions like so:

```
function getTeam() {
    var leagueName = document.getElementById("challengeLeague").value;
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/games?league_name=" + escape(leagueName);
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = updateTeams;
    request.send(null);
} 

function getEvent() {
    var teamName = document.getElementById("challengeTeam").value;
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/gamemp?team_name=" + escape(teamName);
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = updateEvents;
    request.send(null);
}
```

Only the variable assignment in getEvent() is incorrect.  getTeam correctly returns the numerical value.

Both have identical update functions:

```
function updateTeams() { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText); 
            update_select($('select[name=challengeTeam]'), data);
        }  
        else if (request.status == 404) {
            alert("404 error");
        }
        else {
        alert("Error: " + request.status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this in jsfiddle with firefox and chromium, and it worked. are you using IE?

Comment: Can  you post the JS code that is comparing the values with  `document.getElementById("challengeTeam").value;` ?. A common typo is using `=` instead of `==`. You might wanna check and make sure that all your `==`'s are proper. If Django is generating proper html but it is getting changed, this could be a possible reason or Have you edited the values with js in anywhere?

Comment: Updated. See the latest edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mahmud pointed out, I was editing values in javascript with my update_select function:

```
function updateTeams() { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText); 
            update_select($('select[name=challengeTeam]'), data);
        }  
        else if (request.status == 404) {
            alert("404 error");
        }
        else {
        alert("Error: " + request.status);
        }
    }
}

function update_select(select, data) {
    select.find('option').remove();
    for (var k in data) {
        select.append($('<option value="'+data[k]+'">'+data[k]+'</option>'));
    }
}
```

This was setting both the value and text for the new elements to be the string of the team name.  What I really wanted was to set the value attribute to be the key of this data.  This solved my problem:

```
function update_select(select, data) {
    select.find('option').remove();
    for (var k in data) {
        select.append($('<option value="'+ k +'">'+ data[k] +'</option>'));
    }
}
```